# ViewHolder problems on Android? ViewHolder views must not be attached when created

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-viewholder

> ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)
>
> It starts to happen without any explanation. How can I fix this bug?

EditProfileFragment   Where it points the error

```
public class EditProfileFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    //Screen elements
    private ImageView photoImageView;
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private EditText editDescr;
    private List<Spinner> spinners = new ArrayList<Spinner>();
    private List<Chip> tagsSugestoes = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<ChipsInput> mChipsInputList;

    private User user;
    private List<List<Chip>> listaTags = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> listaCategorias;

    private FirebaseUser fbUser = Util.fbUser;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);

        //Fill the Chip's list with 4 chipsInput
        mChipsInputList = new ArrayList<ChipsInput>();
        mChipsInputList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.chipsInput1));
        mChipsInputList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.chipsInput2));
        mChipsInputList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.chipsInput3));
        mChipsInputList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.chipsInput4));

        //Setting elements
        photoImageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        nameTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        Button btLogout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btLogout);
        editDescr = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editDescricao);

        //Set the spinner's list with 4 spinners
        spinners.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
        spinners.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2));
        spinners.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner3));
        spinners.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner4));

        getUserFromFB();

        //Initialize Firebase Auth
        Util.mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Util.mDatabaseRef.child("tagsSuggestions").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tagsSugestoes = new ArrayList<Chip>();
                    for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Chip chip = snap.getValue(Chip.class);
                        tagsSugestoes.add(chip);
                        for(int i=0; i<mChipsInputList.size(); i++){
                            mChipsInputList.get(i).setFilterableList(tagsSugestoes);
                        }
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        listaCategorias = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Fill spinners with categories and set if the user already has it set
        Util.mDatabaseRef.child("categories").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listaCategorias.add("Selecione uma categoria");
                for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    listaCategorias.add(snap.getKey());
                }
                for (int i=0; i<spinners.size(); i++){
                    if(user.getCategorias() != null && user.getCategorias().size() > i)
                        spinners.get(i).setSelection(4);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaCategorias);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinners.get(i).setAdapter(adapter);
                    if(user.getCategorias() != null && user.getCategorias().size() > i)
                        spinners.get(i).setSelection(adapter.getPosition(user.getCategorias().get(i).getCategoria()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //Handle input chips
        for(int i=0; i<mChipsInputList.size(); i++){
            final int finalI = i;
            mChipsInputList.get(i).addChipsListener(new ChipsInput.ChipsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChipAdded(ChipInterface chip, int newSize) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChipRemoved(ChipInterface chip, int newSize) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text) {
                    if(text.length()>0){
                        if(text.charAt(text.length()-1) == ' '){
                            String texto = text.toString();
                            if(!texto.trim().isEmpty())
                                mChipsInputList.get(finalI).addChip(texto.trim(), null);
                            text = "";
                        }}
                }
            });
        }


        Button btUpdate = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btUpdate);

        btUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                List<Chip> listChip;
                //user = new User();
                List<Interesse> interesse = new ArrayList<Interesse>();
                user.setCategorias(interesse);

                //Adding tags Suggestions to a helping String list
                List<String> tagsSugestoesSTR = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i=0; i<tagsSugestoes.size(); i++){
                    tagsSugestoesSTR.add(tagsSugestoes.get(i).getLabel().trim());
                }

                //Handle chips and spinners by each spinner
                for(int i=0; i<spinners.size(); i++){
                    listChip = new ArrayList<Chip>();
                    if(!spinners.get(i).getSelectedItem().equals("Selecione uma categoria")){
                        if(mChipsInputList.get(i).getSelectedChipList().size()>0 && mChipsInputList.get(i) !=null)
                            for(int j=0; j<mChipsInputList.get(i).getSelectedChipList().size(); j++){
                                listChip.add(new Chip(mChipsInputList.get(i).getSelectedChipList().get(j).getLabel()));
                            }
                            user.getCategorias().add(new Interesse(listChip, spinners.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString()));

                        List<String> listaSTR = new ArrayList<String>();
                        //Add Chips texts to helping String list
                        for(int j=0; j<listChip.size(); j++){
                            listaSTR.add(listChip.get(j).getLabel().trim());
                        }
                        //Verify if suggestion is already on database (if it's not then add)
                        for(int j=0; j<listaSTR.size(); j++){
                            if(!tagsSugestoesSTR.contains(listaSTR.get(j).trim())){
                                tagsSugestoes.add(listChip.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                Util.mDatabaseRef.child("tagsSuggestions").setValue(tagsSugestoes);

                updateProfile();
            }
        });

        btLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                logOut();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    //Get user from Firebase Database
    private void getUserFromFB() {
        Util.mUserDatabaseRef.child(Util.fbUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if(user == null){
                    user = new User();
                    user.setNome(Util.fbUser.getDisplayName());
                    user.setUid(Util.fbUser.getUid());
                    Localizacao localizacao = new Localizacao(Util.getLatitude(), Util.getLongitude());
                    user.setLocalizacao(localizacao);
                    List<Interesse> listaCategorias = new ArrayList<Interesse>();
                    List<Chip> chipList = new ArrayList<Chip>();
                    listaCategorias.add(new Interesse(chipList, "Selecione uma categoria"));
                    listaCategorias.add(new Interesse(chipList, "Selecione uma categoria"));
                    listaCategorias.add(new Interesse(chipList, "Selecione uma categoria"));
                    listaCategorias.add(new Interesse(chipList, "Selecione uma categoria"));
                    user.setCategorias(listaCategorias);
                    user.setFotoPerfil(Util.fbUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());
                    Util.mUserDatabaseRef.child(Util.fbUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
                }else{
                    getUserProfile();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Util.mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(Util.mFirebaseAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Util.googleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
        Util.googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    public void goLogInScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (Util.mFirebaseAuthListener != null) {
            Util.mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(Util.mFirebaseAuthListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void logOut() {

        //Logout Facebook
        Util.mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        goLogInScreen();
    }

    //Get, if there is, spinners and chips data
    private void getUserProfile(){
        setBasicInfo();
        Localizacao localizacao = new Localizacao(Util.getLatitude(), Util.getLongitude());
        Util.getmUserDatabaseRef().child(Util.getFbUser().getUid()).child("localizacao").setValue(localizacao);
            if (user.getCategorias() != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < user.getCategorias().size(); i++) {
                    spinners.get(i).setSelection(listaCategorias.indexOf(user.getCategorias().get(i).getCategoria()));
                    if(user.getCategorias().get(i).getTags()!=null)
                    for(int j=0; j<user.getCategorias().get(i).getTags().size(); j++){
                        mChipsInputList.get(i).addChip(user.getCategorias().get(i).getTags().get(j));
                    }
                }
            }

            editDescr.setText(user.getDescricao(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            /*if(user.getTags() != null){
                for (int i=0; i<user.getTags().size(); i++){
                    for (int j=0; j<user.getTags().get(i).size(); j++){
                        mChipsInputList.get(i).addChip(user.getTags().get(i).get(j).getLabel(), null);
                    }
                }}*/
    }

    //Set Basic Info -- Age, Name and Photo
    private void setBasicInfo() {
        if(user.getIdade() > 0){
            if(user.getNome()!=null){
                nameTextView.setText(user.getNome() + ", " + user.getIdade());
            }else{
                nameTextView.setText(fbUser.getDisplayName() + ", " + user.getIdade());
            }
        }else{
            nameTextView.setText(Util.fbUser.getDisplayName());
        }

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getFotoPerfil()).into(photoImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void updateProfile(){
        if(!editDescr.getText().toString().equals(""))
            user.setDescricao(editDescr.getText().toString());
        //user.setFotoPerfil();
        //user.setListaTags(listaTags);

        Util.mUserDatabaseRef.child(Util.fbUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Perfil atualizado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listaTags.clear();
    }
}
```

> Please, someone knows what REALLY causes this error? I know there's a
>   lot of similar questions around here, but none of the solutions works
>   for me. It happens aparently without reason
>
> Error Log

```
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1063390927169899' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=42KB, data=61KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=40KB, data=59KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.xandi.amicer, PID: 16325
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6687)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at com.beloo.widget.chipslayoutmanager.ChipsLayoutManager.layoutDisappearingViews(ChipsLayoutManager.java:767)
        at com.beloo.widget.chipslayoutmanager.ChipsLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(ChipsLayoutManager.java:731)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1450)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:516)
        at com.pchmn.materialchips.views.ScrollViewMaxHeight.onMeasure(ScrollViewMaxHeight.java:47)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1450)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:516)
        at com.pchmn.materialchips.views.ScrollViewMaxHeight.onMeasure(ScrollViewMaxHeight.java:47)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1296)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:340)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1632)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:809)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19759)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2283)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1370)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6348)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

> SectionPageAdapter

```
   package com.example.xandi.amicer;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                TabPerfil tabPerfil = new TabPerfil();
                return tabPerfil;
            case 1:
                TabHome tabHome = new TabHome();
                return tabHome;
            case 2:
                TabGrupos tabGrupos = new TabGrupos();
                return tabGrupos;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return "PERFIL";
            case 1:
                return "HOME";
            case 2:
                return "GRUPOS";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for attachtorroot?

Comment: can you share SectionPagerAdapter's codes ?

Comment: I Updated the code, Your suspect is that it could be a problem with the fragments?

Comment: The probleme is related with a `RecyclerView`. Could you update the code for the Recycler's adapter?

Comment: Recycler's adapter? What if I don't have one? What does it do?